# Removing a line from multiple Github files at once

Tags: html, git, github

I'm attempting to edit a line out of the footer file in every single one of my html files on Github.

https://github.com/GiacomoLaw/IF-Charts

Anyway that I can do this all at one time?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to upload multiple files at once with Git? Or edit them with Git?

Comment: I'm trying to edit all the files at once with git.

Comment: I don't think that is possible... Git is a version control software, not an IDE... You're probably going to have to do it with an IDE, such as Atom (Find and replace would probably be your best bet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an IDE or a decent advanced text editor and do a find and replace in project. Often this function is mapped to the keybinding Ctrl+Shift+F.

Here's a link for the Atom editor: http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/find-and-replace/

Sublime Text: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html

JetBrains editors also support this function: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html